# Deduplicating stash output

Tags: add-on, stash

I'm trying to create a dropdown filter based off a custom field in channel entries.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="events"}

  {!-- Build the complete listing --}
  {exp:stash:append name="listing"}
    <li><a href="{title_permalink='events/detail'}">{title}</a></li>
  {/exp:stash:append}

  {!-- Build the dropdown filter options. This is what I want to contain unique values --}
  {exp:stash:append name="locations"}
    <option>{event_location}</option>
  {/exp:stash:append}

{/exp:channel:entries}

<select>
  {exp:stash:get name="locations"}
</select>

<ul>
  {exp:stash:get name="listing"}
</ul>
```

This might output something like:

```
<select>
  <option>USA</option>
  <option>USA</option>
  <option>Australia</option>
  <option>Canada</option>
</select>

<ul>
  <li><a href="...">First US Event</a></li>
  <li><a href="...">Second US Event</a></li>
  <li><a href="...">Australian Event</a></li>
  <li><a href="...">Canadian Event</a></li>
</ul>
```

However, I want the values in the `{exp:stash:get name="locations"}` to only be output once.
ie. USA once, not twice.
Is this possible?

**Edit:**
Turns out it does what I wanted on its own in the code I posted.
However my *actual* code had a `{count}` variable thrown in for testing.

```
{exp:stash:append name="locations"}
  <option>{count} - {event_location}</option>
{/exp:stash:append}
```

The `{count}` made each row unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stash will automatically deduplicate the values if you are setting the exact same value more than once.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use the `{exp:stash:get_list}` tag pair you have access to the `unique="yes"` **[parameter](https://github.com/croxton/Stash#unique--yesno)**. Might try it on the `exp:stash:get` tag.

Comment: Turns out there was a bit of stupidity on my side. I'll explain it in my question. Although I'd like to know an example of how to properly use the `unique="yes"` parameter.

Comment: I've actually never used Stash so can't help with an example. Take a look at the docs that I linked to in my answer. Might help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a query to do this instead of the channel:entries tag:

```
{exp:query sql="SELECT DISTINCT field_id_1 as location FROM exp_channel_data WHERE channel_id = '2'"}
    {exp:stash:append name="locations"}
            <option>{location}</option>
    {/exp:stash:append}
{/exp:query}
```

Change `channel_id` to match the ID of your events channel and `field_id_1` to match your location field ID

Comment: Technically that does work but I want to know if it's possible to do it with Stash. I'll update my example code to explain why.

Comment: Well you didn't say that! :)

Comment: I thought the title of the post implied Stash. I'll update it all in a minute.